# Hover over div not working IE10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to make a rectangular scalable div that has a transitional hover state. My code seems to work great in Chrome and Firefox, but IE10 simply refuses to entertain me. Below is my code and CSS example. Any help would be great.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="quote">
        Interesting Quote
        <p class="name">Quote Author</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.quote {
    font-size: 2em;
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 5%;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    margin: .5%;
    background-color: #99F;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.name {
    font-size: .5em;
    color: #000;
}

.quote:hover {
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
    background-color: #000;    
}

.quote:hover .name {
    transition: color 0.5s;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DIqfr/

Comment: Ok, sorry I hadn't put a <!DOCTYPE html> in there - I've been bashing my head against this for nearly 2 hours!